# Type discriminators - how to restrict parameters

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say I want to do the following:

```
type Car = {
    type: 'car'
}

type House = {
    type: 'house'
}

add('car', {type: 'car'})   // < this is fine.

add('house', {type: 'car'}) // < this should cause a compile time error.
```

Is it possible to write an `add` method that enforces this constraint?

Another requirement is, that there is no limit in what `type`s you can add.
The only limit should be, that the `type`s must match.

[TS-Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJygXigbwLACgq6qSALigHIBjRE7AX22wOgAkB7AVwGdpVMc8HiSACzacqWWlmxlmAO3bAocACZKUUADwAVAPIAjAFZQIAD2AQZS9un5QA1hBDUANFE0BpBwD4AFPZDF5BABLGQBzF2YDYh0DAEoUT3RsPCgAegAqKAA6HKh01Jo6LGUlb3JKFzQbcoQSanjcVNSNfEEgq3aoADMQiCyikrLhDggSSuqKWvq05vVWzvZhgBtVGWYFXWgwZnZ2IN0lvqA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly modified your code to make it work as intended:

```
const add = <TObj extends {type: TKey}, TKey extends string>(key: TKey, obj: TObj) => {
    /* ... */
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwTAvDAPAFQPICMBWMApgB5RFgIQwDeUAngA5EBcMmA0kfQL4A07LvWJkKVGNABOASzABzAHwAKANbc2nbgJAENefAEpUC2gFgAUDCswA9ACoYAOmcw7NizwsXECJQHJgOEk-ATomVhgAoL8eIysbGwwYKAALaWp0mAAzWSJHL3MffxSQAFcIIhDaBmY2KODY20T0ZLTqCBLSgBtkMBBYXCIYRhAICGlcLrygA)

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why Typescript knows to infer literal types here. Generally, the language is pretty eager to assume any literal string has type `string` and not get more specific than that.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo That happens during variable assignment, when TypeScript conservatively infers `let name = 'house';` as type `string` instead of `house`, but when using generic types I always see it infer the literal type whenever possible.

Comment: That's very good to know. Thank you! I definitely learned something today.